# Create an instance of DirectoryEntry for use in test

Tags: c#, reflection, active-directory

I'm attempting to create an instance of a DirectoryEntry so that I can use this to test some code that will be passed a DirectoryEntry.  However, despite a lot of trying I can't find a way to instantiate a DE and initialize it's PropertyCollection.

I have the following code which was taken and modified from [another answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069106/how-to-mock-system-directoryservices-searchresult) that was doing the same process but for the SearchResult object.  It seems that the Add method has been completely disabled and I can't find a way to call a constructor on PropertyCollection to pass in some properties.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

public static class DirectoryEntryFactory
{
    const BindingFlags nonPublicInstance = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
    const BindingFlags publicInstance = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;

    public static DirectoryEntry Construct<T>(T anonInstance)
    {
        var e = GetUninitializedObject<DirectoryEntry>();

        SetPropertiesField(e);

        var dictionary = (IDictionary)e.Properties;
        var type = typeof(T);
        var propertyInfos = type.GetProperties(publicInstance);

        foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
        {
            var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(anonInstance, null);
            var valueCollection = GetUninitializedObject<PropertyValueCollection>();
            var innerList = GetInnerList(valueCollection);
            innerList.Add(value);

            var lowerKey = propertyInfo.Name.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            // These both throw exceptions saying you can't add to a PropertyCollection
            //(typeof(PropertyCollection)).InvokeMember("System.Collections.IDictionary.Add", nonPublicInstance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, dictionary, new object[] { propertyInfo.Name, value });
            //dictionary.Add(lowerKey, propertyCollection);
        }

        return e;
    }

    private static ArrayList GetInnerList(object propertyCollection)
    {
        var propertyInfo = typeof(PropertyValueCollection).GetProperty("InnerList", nonPublicInstance);
        return (ArrayList)propertyInfo.GetValue(propertyCollection, null);
    }

    private static void SetPropertiesField(DirectoryEntry e)
    {
        var propertiesField = typeof(DirectoryEntry).GetField("propertyCollection", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        propertiesField.SetValue(e, GetUninitializedObject<PropertyCollection>());
    }

    private static T GetUninitializedObject<T>()
    {
        return (T)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

usage is intended to be

```
DirectoryEntry e = DirectoryEntryFactory.Construct(new { attr1 = "Hello", attr2 = "World"});
```

I'm hoping I've missed something as I'm pretty new to using reflection in anger.

Comment: Adam, did you actually manage to implement this with a working Properties implementation? I'm having the same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056483/mocking-the-properties-property-of-directoryentry).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with DirectoryEntry itself, but I'm a big fan of the Adapter pattern for testing. It is an annoyance that you would have to do such a thing, but the code itself is trivial and the classes can be placed in a project folder to hide them away from your main project.

For example, I have a FileInfoAdapter and DirectoryInfoAdapter that wrap those classes that touch the filesystem.

FileInfoAdapter:

```
public class FileInfoAdapter : IFileInfo
{
    private readonly FileSystemInfo _fi;

    public FileInfoAdapter(string fileName)
        : this(new FileInfo(fileName))
    { }

    public FileInfoAdapter(FileSystemInfo fi)
    {
        _fi = fi;
    }

    public string Name { get { return _fi.Name; } }
    public string FullName { get { return _fi.FullName; } }
    public bool Exists { get { return _fi.Exists; } }
}
```

Comment: I had thought about wrapping the object but was hoping there was another answer.  I think I'll probably give in and wrap it for now instead of waiting for a perfect solution - but it would be interesting to know if there is a way to do this properly.

Comment: @Adam - When it comes to library code that doesn't implement interfaces, I don't think there's anything wrong with an Adapter. I use the pattern quite a bit.