# Mocking the "Properties" property of DirectoryEntry

Tags: c#, unit-testing, active-directory, moq, directoryservices

I'm trying to unit test some Active Directory code, pretty much the same as outlined in this question:

[Create an instance of DirectoryEntry for use in test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966161/create-an-instance-of-directoryentry-for-use-in-test)

The accepted answer suggests implementing a wrapper/adapter for the `DirectoryEntry` class, which I have:

```
public interface IDirectoryEntry : IDisposable
{
    PropertyCollection Properties { get; }
}

public class DirectoryEntryWrapper : DirectoryEntry, IDirectoryEntry
{
}
```

The problem is that the "*Properties*" property on my `IDirectoryEntry` mock is not initialised. Trying to set the mock up like this:

```
this._directoryEntryMock = new Mock<IDirectoryEntry>();
this._directoryEntryMock.Setup(m => m.Properties)
                        .Returns(new PropertyCollection());
```

Results in the following error:

**The type 'System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection' has no constructors defined**

As I understand it, this error is thrown when trying to instantiate a class with internal constructors only:

[The type '...' has no constructors defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958358/the-type-has-no-constructors-defined)

I have tried to write a wrapper/adapter for the `PropertyCollection` class but without a public constructor I can't figure out how to instantiate or inherit from the class.

So how can I mock/setup the "*Properties*" property on the `DirectoryEntry` class for testing purposes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that you'll be able to mock or create an instance of `PropertyCollection`. There are ways of overcoming this, but they require you to convert your derived wrapper class to be more of an actual wrapper, encapsulating a `DirectoryEntry` object and providing accessors, not extending it. Once you've done that, you have these options:

1. Define the return type of the `Properties` property as one of the underlying collection types that `PropertyCollection` implements (`IDictionary`, `ICollection` or `IEnumerable`), if that is sufficient for your needs
2. Create an encapsulating wrapper class with an interface for `PropertyCollection`, and create a new one to wrap `directoryEntry.Properties` each time the `Properties` accessor is called
3. Create methods on `IDirectoryEntry`/`DirectoryEntryWrapper` that return what you need without having to expose a `Properties` property

1 might be fine as a workaround, if you're OK accessing the properties through one of the underlying collection types. 2 will require you to implement every method and property of `PropertiesCollection` in the wrapper, calling through to the encapsulated object underneath, but would be the most flexible. The easiest (but least flexible) is 3.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to Chris's suggestions here is a code sample for my eventual solution (I went with his option 1):

```
public interface IDirectoryEntry : IDisposable
{
    IDictionary Properties { get; }
}

public class DirectoryEntryWrapper : IDirectoryEntry
{
    private readonly DirectoryEntry _entry;

    public DirectoryEntryWrapper(DirectoryEntry entry)
    {
        _entry = entry;
        Properties = _entry.Properties;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_entry != null)
        {
            _entry.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public IDictionary Properties { get; private set; }
}
```

Used as follows:

```
this._directoryEntryMock = new Mock<IDirectoryEntry>();
this._directoryEntryMock
        .Setup(m => m.Properties)
        .Returns(new Hashtable()
        {
            { "PasswordExpirationDate", SystemTime.Now().AddMinutes(-1) }
        });
```